# Eiffel 18.07 trying to get an ODBC connection running from examples

Tags: odbc, sudo, eiffel

Trying to just compile Eiffel_18.07/examples/store/esql/ on Debian 9 I've got following error:

```
In file included from od243.c:202:0,
                 from big_file_C8_c.c:42:
/opt/Eiffel_18.07/library/store/dbms/rdbms/odbc/Clib/odbc.h:27:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sql.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'big_file_C8_c.o' failed
make[1]: *** [big_file_C8_c.o] Error 1
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'C8/Cobj8.o' failed
make: *** [C8/Cobj8.o] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

an `apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev odbc-postgresql` **got me further** to

```
gcc: error: /opt/Eiffel_18.07/library/store/spec/linux-x86-64/lib/libodbc.a: No such file or directory
Makefile:177: recipe for target 'esql' failed
```

When I try to go to `/opt/Eiffel_18.07/library/store/dbms/rdbms/odbc/Clib` thinking I'll be able to generate some code to get it working following the `/opt/Eiffel_18.07/library/store/install` into `/opt/Eiffel_18.07/library/store/dbms/rdbms/odbc/Clib` trying a `sudo /opt/Eiffel_18.07/studio/spec/linux-x86-64/bin/finish_freezing -library` 
got

```
cp: cannot stat '/usr/include/eiffelstudio-18.07/config.sh': No such file or directory
Can't find config.sh.
Makefile.SH: 6: .: Can't open ./config.sh
```

Being a fan of Eiffel, it doesn't seem to be working out of the box and I didn't find enough documentation to get it working :-()

Comment: Maybe you don't have the odbc debian development package. Try to use `sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev` .

Comment: Thx, then `gcc: error: /opt/Eiffel_18.07/library/store/spec/linux-x86-64/lib/libodbc.a: No such file or directory` what do I have to do with origin package of Eiffel studio to get working an ODBC Connection, if possible postgresql

Comment: I am not an expert of odbc. Sorry. I know that the explication of Alexander Kogtenkov should work alright to make odbc work properly in Eiffel. But if you are looking for a Postgresql connector for EiffelStore, there is an Eiffel User that have create one. See there: http://eiffel.641255.n2.nabble.com/eiffel-users-Postgres-connector-td7583712.html . The link of the attachment is: http://eiffel.641255.n2.nabble.com/attachment/7583722/0/postgresql.zip .

Comment: Thx @LouisM somebody from ISE wrote me a doc which will be on the website. The connector actually seems to exist into the estudio bundle, didn't try the one from the user you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sequence of steps that allowed me to build the example on *Ubuntu 16.04*:

1. Download and unpack *EiffelStudio* in a new directory (let's denote the absolute path as `#ES#`).
2. Set environment variables:

   ```
   export ISE_EIFFEL=#ES#
   export ISE_PLATFORM=linux-x86-64
   export PATH=$PATH:$ISE_EIFFEL/studio/spec/$ISE_PLATFORM/bin
   ```

   These commands assume `bash`, replace them with equivalents when using another shell.
3. Install package `unixodbc-dev`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
   ```
4. Compile C code of the Eiffel library *store*:

   ```
   cd ${ISE_EIFFEL}/library/store/dbms/rdbms/odbc/Clib
   finish_freezing -library
   ```

   **Note:** no need to prefix `finish_freezing` with `sudo` unless *EiffelStudio* has been installed to a path without write permissions for ordinary users. Otherwise (e.g., for the original poster of the problem on *Debian 9*, where *EiffelStudio* has been installed under `/opt`), permissions have to be elevated:

   ```
   sudo -i
   cd ${ISE_EIFFEL}/library/store/dbms/rdbms/odbc/Clib
   finish_freezing -library
   exit
   ```
5. Compile the example `esql`:

   ```
   cd ${ISE_EIFFEL}/examples/store/esql
   ec -c_compile -config esql.ecf -target esql_odbc
   ```
6. Run the compiled executable:

   ```
   ./EIFGENs/esql_odbc/W_code/esql
   ```

Comment: Thx, if I dont give the finish_freezing command the sudo rights got various right errors like `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘../../../../spec/linux-x86-64’: Permission denied` which makes sense

Comment: Finally got it doing a `sudo -i` and then doing the finish_freezing. Seems that the only sudo command does not set the good variables, the strange behaviour is `sudo echo $PATH
/home/pg/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/Eiffel_18.07/studio/spec/linux-x86-64/bin:/home/pg/bin:/opt/Zotero_linux-x86_6` so find how but not why ;-)

Comment: So, your answer was perfect and helpful but to be the one solving my problem could we add the sudo problem solution? I'll edit the answer and maybe you'll find a better solution

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud It must be related to permissions. Have you installed EiffelStudio to the path that has no write permissions for regular users?

Answer (score 0):

Login as root changed my problem instead of only doing a sudo of the finish_freezing command

```
    sudo -i
```

and then

```
    cd ${ISE_EIFFEL}/library/store/dbms/rdbms/odbc/Clib
    finish_freezing -library
```